# Link not appearing in same line as the text

Tags: html, css

I would like the link to appear in same line as the text in my div. Now it is appearing in next line.

Currently the situation is

```
Some text
http://example.com/very-long-link/very-long-link/very-long-link/very-long-link/very-long-link/very-long-link/very-long-link/very-long-link.html
```

Expected result is instead:

```
Some text http://example.com/very-long-link/very-long-link/very-long-link/very-long-link/very-long-link/very-long-link/very-long-link/very-long-link.html
```

HTML Code:

```
<div>
  <ol>
    <li>
      Some text <a href="#">http://example.com/very-long-link/very-long-link/very-long-link/very-long-link/very-long-link/very-long-link/very-long-link/very-long-link.html</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
a {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: inline;
}
```

> Updated:
>
> By adding and removing hyphen it gives different results. To reproduce the issue please resize browser window to less than 1000px in jsfiddle.
>   https://jsfiddle.net/6xnqnwmw/

Comment: It is already appearing as you wish. [Even without any CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/dzp2y0np/). Please, check the code before asking.

Comment: Sorry but also applying your [CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/dzp2y0np/1/) I cannot reproduce the issue. Are you sure there is no more style applied?

Comment: Please refer the jsfiddle link in the updated description to reproduce the issue.

Comment: may it help you? [https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/)

Answer (score 0):

The text link is probably overflowing the li elements (max) width.

You could set `overflow: visible` or increase the width of the li element so the link fits on the same line in css.

> Edit
>
> It was a problem with overflowing. I got it fixed by making the li
>   width very wide. (Bit of a hack but might work for you).
>
> https://jsfiddle.net/mb9aLaLa/1/
>
> Edit 2: You can use word-wrap:break-all for this
>   https://jsfiddle.net/mb9aLaLa/3/

Comment: Please refer the jsfiddle link in the updated description to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Actually I have a div container with fixed width so the link text needs to wrap inside so `overflow: hidden` might not serve the purpose.